# Mix AP and bread flour for bagels?

Tags: flour, bagels

I live in a rural part of the country. NO BAGEL SHOPS! I've started experimenting on making my own. Bread flour makes the end product too dense. AP flour too light. Recipe calls for 4 cups bread flour a cup and a half of water. Anyone know what a good ratio of flours and water might be?

Comment: Have you looked at different recipes ? did they have different flour/water ratios ?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!  I'm afraid it's not really clear what advice you're looking for. The title of your question asks about mixing AP/Bread flour, but your ask in the question is flour::water ratios.  What do you want to know?

Comment: So sorry for the confusion. I think I'm right in that bread flour takes less water? If I use 2 cups each of bread flour and AP flour Would I use the same cup and a half for my bagel dough?

Comment: Instead of mixing flours, you can also try playing with the hydration ratio. That will also have an effect on how dense/light your product will be.